# Obstipation + toxic antibiotic intake!

Tags: health, rabbits, medicines, poison

My bunny has constipation for last couple days, last night I noticed she has a wobbly tooth too (I easily pulled it out-root was necrotic with a little pus inside) so in panic and fear of formation of an abscess i gave her clindamycin per os :(
Took her to the vet this morning and he told me that I made a terrible mistake (I read about consequences). Bunny is still not defecating, though I was force feeding her(fresh dandelion leaves), giving her activated charcoal, oil, simethicone, flax seed slime... I'm desperate and don't know what can I do more to help her. Did anyone have similar experience?

Comment: what did the vet advise?

Comment: For now just to continue with this therapy :/

Comment: If there has been no poops for 3 days, did the vet check for blockage (xray/ultra sound)? If no stool and no check for blockage, find a vet who will check and will consider surgery.  If there are some poops please describe what kind of poops you are seeing and how many a day.

Answer (score 2):

We have a list of [What antibiotics should not be given to a rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5736) it includes Clindamycin.   Addressing the treatment of infection is beyond the scope of this answer, but some suggestions about gut motility may be helpful.

GI stasis can occur when the rabbits gut stops moving food through it's system.  It is a prevalent issue with rabbits.  First course treatments focus on getting things moving again. Second course treatment is limiting risk of future episode, which mostly is centered around diet improvements.

If your rabbit has not produced any poop for 3 days, surgery may be required to remove blockage.  Be aware stomach/gut surgery is very high risk, my rabbit surgeon who is very skilled reports a 50% mortality rate, it generally a last resort option.

Non-surgical treatment generally includes:

- A gut motility drug such as cisapride (Propulsid) or metoclopramide (Reglan) {*per your comment your vet is using menbutone to increase motility, I am not familiar with this drug*}
- Simethicone to address gas and related pain
- Abdominal massage and forced feeding, of [Critical Care](http://www.oxbowanimalhealth.com/vets/products/critical_care)

Without more detail it hard to define what that actual cause is. The most likely cause of a blockage is that wool block (hair ball) has moved from the stomach and blocked the intestine see this [related case study of my rabbit](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-is-wool-block-in-rabbits/720#720) who had reoccurring GI Stasis issues.

The most likely causes of non-blockage GI stasis are; stress, dehydration, pain or insufficient fiber (hay). In your case you report a tooth issue, the pain from that may have decreased intake and lead to the GI stasis event.

Related reading

- [Gastrointestinal Stasis: The Silent Killer](http://rabbit.org/gastrointestinal-stasis-the-silent-killer-2/)

Related questions.

- [What reasons could there be for my rabbit not defecating?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6792)
- [Why is adding hay to a rabbit's diet important?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/551)

Comment: I had the same problem with my previous bunny few years ago, she had enlarged lymph nodes all over her body for about 5 months, at that time she was 5,5 yrs (I suspected on lymphoma, vet have never made diagnostics) then she stopped eating and pooping, x-ray showed noting, she ended up on surgery table, died 12 h later :(((  We went to the same vet (he is the most familiar with rabbits among the other vets in the city)

Comment: We did x-ray, stomach is not emptying! It's full and over bloated, air in intestines, but there is no obvious cause of obstruction, she has temperature (40,2 C). She got dexamethasone, menbutone and baytril. Seing the vet again in the morning. I am afraid to give her anything to eat

Comment: @Mimi Gas is not unusual see [Can rabbits fart?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/can-rabbits-fart) not feeding is almost never a good idea.  Is she passing any poops at all?

Comment: No, not at all. This morning I was force feeding her, but in the afternoon she wouldn't swallow anything

Comment: @Mimi I have updated the answer with more detail. The treatment you and your vet are using is reasonable. My vet would use Reglan in place of Menbutone.  I would include tummy massage and Simethicone with the force feeding.  If there is no blockage, the gut is not moving (GI stasis), unfortunately GI stasis is big issue with rabbits, if you can't get it moving again, she will not survive.