# Rabbit Eating Dog Food

Tags: health, rabbits, diet

My rabbit has been eating dog food for 2 weeks now. I can't explain why but I'm just wondering if it is ok for her to eat it. I have a dog kennel outside and when I let my dog out she goes in to eat the food. Is there any health concerns about her eating dog food? Should I attempt to stop her from eating dog food?

Comment: How/why is dog food available for your rabbit to eat?

Comment: I have a dog kennel outside with my dog in it. When I let him out she goes in and starts eating. @JamesJenkins

Comment: Last time this happened to me, my rabbit was recovering from a massive op . I dont know if rabbits fo this if they feel they're lacking vitamins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rabbits are herbivores and should not eat food containing meat or dairy. A little is unlikely to have hurt her yet, but allowing her to have regular access to it is not good for her.

Answer (score 3):

My rabbits will eat dig food if they have access to it. One would even chase away the dog from his dinner aggressively in order to eat his kibble. They are not attracted to tinned dog food. It is because dog kibble has very high cereal and grain content. That being said, it is NOT good for them as it has animal protein and fat added as well as other derivatives, high fat content, vitamins and minerals that would not normally be a part of rabbit's diet. I would be worried if my rabbits consumed any large or regular amounts of it but a tiny quantity they occasionally managed to steal has not caused any trouble so far.

Comment: This is a very good answer but it could be improved with some references and added detail about rabbits consuming animal fat and proteins.   We could also use a related question and answer about rabbits and yogurt.  There is some [research here](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/how-fresh-should-cecotropes-be-when-used-to-recolonize-a-different-rabbit/2010#2010) that you are welcome to leverage on if you would like to post a question and answer about yogurt.