# My rabbit is wet and not moving

Tags: health, rabbits

this is my first time to have a pet rabbit. I bought them before christmas day. This past few days, the weather is very bad because of typhoon. I forgot to bring them inside our house so they are very wet and so their housing. My male rabbit now, is not eating and I found brown and watery substance in his butt. What should I do to this? There's no veterinary clinic here. I already wipe him, but he still giving off those brown substance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am sorry to hear about your rabbit. A wet rabbit that is not eating is in a medical emergency.

1. Get the rabbit warm and dry
2. Get food into the rabbit
3. After the rabbit is warm and fed, clean it's bottom with a little warm water (just on the dirty area, and dry them again)
4. Read some [posts here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits) and learn more about keeping rabbits as pets.

Make dry hay available, if your rabbit does not start eating some with in a few minutes, try offering a carrot, piece of fruit, or pureed vegetables like squash.

Rabbits that go 24 hours without eating tend to die, keeping food moving through them is critical during any illness.

The brown stuff on his butt is probably diarrhea, getting enough fiber in their diet is important as an important part of their diet is [cecotropes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/617/do-bunnies-eat-their-droppings) and having diarrhea disrupts that.

**Related**

[What should be in a rabbit first aid kit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1783)

Comment: Thank you for this info. I will surely use this in the near future. But sad to say he died after 30 minutes when I posted my question :(

Comment: @Port8080 - That's unfortunate news. I might offer the suggestion, as a former rabbit person as well, that it would be much, much, better to keep your rabbits indoors. They're social creatures and need stimulation and contact. Also, they're not the same as their wild cousins. With litter training and proper home proofing, they're as friendly to keep as any animal.

Comment: Noted! Thanks @JohnCavan . I am starting to build rabbit's house indoors.