# What pellets are rabbits eating in Watership Down?

Tags: diet, rabbits, literature

In the book  [Watership Down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watership_Down) the rabbits are often "eating pellets".  My pet rabbit eats food pellets I buy from the pet store, but I don't see how that would apply to the rabbits in Watership Down.

What pellets are rabbits eating in Watership Down?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't appear to be a question about pets, but to be speculative about the action of fictional characters in a classic fiction novel.

Comment: Related [New tag literature](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/new-tag-literature)

Comment: The author of "Watership down" had studied wild european rabbits for his life time in Great Britain. So the "fictional" part of the story should be seen in relation to this fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably [cecotropes.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/617/do-bunnies-eat-their-droppings)

A rabbit's digestive system is not as efficient as that of a larger herbivore. There is a lot of nutrition left after food has made one pass through, and it's been concentrated and pretreated by digestive enzymes... and rabbits may send it through for a second pass.

They do distinguish between cecotropes and feces, so the gutter insult near the end of the book is still appropriately rude.