# Should I worry that my rabbit is leaving connected poops?

Tags: health, rabbits, defecation, feces

My bunny has been pooping connected poops (see picture).  I sometimes see a couple of these when cleaning the litter box. Is something wrong? What causes this?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there are two concerns here (assuming colour is accurate)

1) the connection appears to be fur which suggests the rabbit has an increased chance of going into [stasis/gut immobility from wool block](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/692/193)

2) the colour of the faeces is quite dark, and maybe a bit small which can suggest a poor diet (unless this is an exposure issue with the picture?) a normal rabbit poo should be a golden colour e.g.

[image: picture of rabbit poo]

as the picture suggests, size is also a consideration but this will vary with breed

overall i'd suggest reviewing the rabbit diet and in particular making sure it is [having enough hay (it should be ~90% of their diet)](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/551/193). You could also look at grooming your rabbit so that it isn't eating so much fur.

Comment: Are... are those raisins in the lower part of the picture?

Comment: @JoshDM I... wouldn't recommend eating one.

Comment: Low volumes of connected poop from fur isn't anything to specifically worry about. Rabbits do groom themselves and so some ingested fur is normal.

Comment: Smaller bunnies have smaller droppings.  A Netherland dwarf's are less than half the diameter of an English lop's. With out knowing the type of rabbit I do not know how you can say it is too small.