# What evidence could I check to detect a "rabbit experienced" vet?

Tags: rabbits, veterinarian

I have recently learned, that a vet in Germany do not have "rabbits" in his regular studies.  (If this is not correct, please let me know!)

So my question is: How could I check, if the new vet I want to take my rabbits to is "rabbit experienced", if I have no hearsay to count on?

(I imagine things like certificates, record of study, advanced training)

(As addition it would be interesting to learn about other countries base studies and possibilities to advance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 kinds of vets when it comes to rabbits.

1. Some vets do not see rabbits at all
2. Some vets do see rabbits, but not might not be skilled at rabbit care
3. Some vets see rabbits and are VERY GOOD at caring for rabbits.

Optimally you only want to visit a vet in group three.  There are a number pet rabbit organizations and rescues that will help you find a good rabbit vet in your area. Contact a local rabbit rescue in your area or there is a list here https://rabbit.org/vet-listings/

Above excerpt from my [existing answer here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/21108/13)

The rabbit.org page does not currently list anything in Germany, but as @snow says in [their answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/26028/13) finding and asking local rabbit owners is also a good option

Additionally while you are looking for the best vet, create a [Rabbit First Aid Kit](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1783/13) and learn how to treat the most common issues.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do here is investigate local rabbit or small animal clubs or forums and ask for personal recommendations for vets.

Personal experience is always very useful in cases like this, even when vets do advertise knowledge of different kinds of pets.